# Why am I unable to play CS:GO through Steam Family Sharing anymore?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive, steam-family-sharing

I have a friend who family shares me some games and I can play all of them except one: CSGO.

- I was able to play it before.
- He's not playing something either: I only cannot play CSGO, but I can play other games.
- It shows "purchase" where it should say "play". When I try to launch it takes me to the Store

Does anyone know why this changed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you mean:

> Actually, I mean it shows "purchase" where it should say "play".

and

> Ok thank you, but the problem still exists, I said that I can play all other games except CSGO, you said I can't play his "games". So basically I cannot play CSGO when he isn't playing anything, I can play other games.

It is because:

## Counter-Strike: Global Offensive has been excluded from Steam's Family sharing services.

It says so right here:
[image]

Besides, wasn't fully open anyway when it was accessible through family sharing. You could:

- Not access any official or VAC-secured servers
- Not have an inventory, even with actual CS:GO items in your inventory, and:
- Only access insecure servers or play offline.

Did I mention it's also free-to-play now?

Answer (score -1):

From the official family sharing post on steam:

*Steam Family Library Sharing allows family members and their guests to play one another's games while earning their own Steam achievements and saving their own game progress to the Steam Cloud.

If you see a family member's installed game that you want to play you can send them a request to authorize you. Once authorized, their library of Steam games becomes available for you to access, download and play.*

Be careful that two people can't play at the same moment on Steam Family Sharing.

**So, if he's playing CSGO or any other game in his library you can't play his games.**

Comment: Ok thank you, but the problem still exists, I said that I can play all other games except CSGO, you said I can't play his "games". So basically I cannot play CSGO when he isn't playing anything, I can play other games.